# Retrieving from an array an object that satisfies some characteristics

Tags: ruby, search

I have some objects in an array `objects`. Given a certain property-value pair, I need a function that returns the first object that matches this. For example, given `objects.byName "John"`, it should return the first object with `name: "John"`.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
def self.byName name
  ID_obj_by_name = {}
  @@objects.each_with_index do |o, index|
    ID_obj_by_name[o.name] = index
  end
  @@objects[ID_obj_by_name[name]]
end
```

But it seems very slow, and is using a lot of memory. How can I improve this?

Comment: Aside from your question (for which [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) is the answer, as shown by @Ursus), a few things stand out: 1) `ID_obj_by_name`, since it begins with a capital letter, is a constant. You can't use assignment to create a constant within a method: `def a; A=1; end #=>  SyntaxError: dynamic constant assignment`. Make that (say) `id_obj_by_name`. 2) One Ruby convention is to use *snake case* for names of variables and methods: `by_name` rather than `byName`. You don't have to follow that convention, but 99%+ of us do.  (cont.)...

Comment: ...3) Your method must be within an unspecified class, as class variables  (@@objects) cannot be accessed from "top level". You therefore should wrap the method in the class definition.

Answer (score 1):

If you need performance, you should consider this approach:

```
require 'benchmark'

class Foo
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def name
    @name
  end
end

# Using array ######################################################################
test = []
500000.times do |i|
  test << Foo.new("ABC" + i.to_s + "#!@#@!DS")
end

puts "using array"
time = Benchmark.measure {
  result = test.find { |o| o.name == "ABC250000#!@#@!DS" }
}
puts time
####################################################################################
# Using a hash #####################################################################

test = {}
i_am_your_object = Object.new
500000.times do |i|
  test["ABC" + i.to_s + "#!@#@!DS"] = i_am_your_object
end

puts "using hash"
time = Benchmark.measure {
  result = test["ABC250000#!@#@!DS"]
}
puts time
####################################################################################
```

Results:

```
using array
  0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.060884)
using hash
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000005)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
def self.by_name name
  @@objects.find { |o| o.name == name }
end
```